# Partial derivatives of bilinear Sampling

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing

I'm going over the paper **Spatial Transformer Networks** ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02025)). On section 3.3 they introduce bilinear sampling kernel (Eq. 5)
$$
V_{i}^{c}=\sum_{n}^{H} \sum_{m}^{W} U_{n m}^{c} \max \left(0,1-\left|x_{i}^{s}-m\right|\right) \max \left(0,1-\left|y_{i}^{s}-n\right|\right),
$$ 
and it's partial derivative (Eq. 6)
$$
\frac{\partial V_{i}^{c}}{\partial U_{n m}^{c}}=\sum_{n}^{H} \sum_{m}^{W} \max \left(0,1-\left|x_{i}^{s}-m\right|\right) \max \left(0,1-\left|y_{i}^{s}-n\right|\right).
$$

Since we take the derivative w.r.t. $U^c_{nm}$, it seems to me like the partial derivative should be
$$
\frac{\partial V_{i}^{c}}{\partial U_{n m}^{c}}=\max \left(0,1-\left|x_{i}^{s}-m\right|\right) \max \left(0,1-\left|y_{i}^{s}-n\right|\right),
$$
otherwise, the indices $m,n$ of the lhs is meaningless, and all of the partial derivatives will be identical.

Did I miss anything regarding the definition of $V^c_i$, $x^s_i$, or $U^c_{nm}$?